# latest nvim error, Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvim

I got this error when running neovim v0.5.0-dev+1308 (using the nvim.appimage) for the first time, I don't know what could it be or how to fix it, any help would be appreciated since I cannot use neovim which is my work editor.

uname -a:

```
Linux acc 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #55-Microsoft Sat Oct 06 18:05:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If i try with: `sudo ./nvim`:

```
./nvim: 1: ./nvim: ELF: not found
./nvim: 2: ./nvim: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

On version dev+1311 this shows up when I run `sudo ./nvim`

```
./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: 1: ./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: ELF: not found
./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: 2: ./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: ▒▒: not found
./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: 3: ./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: @8
                                                                 @$@@@0ppp      I       I ▒I▒i▒i▒▒8R ▒▒K▒▒k▒▒k`▒▒▒DD▒I▒i▒i P▒td▒CA▒CA▒CA▒▒Q▒tdR▒td▒I▒i▒iP▒P▒/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNU▒wvP▒HzƋ]▒▒n▒: not found
./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: 4: ./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: ▒: not found
./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: 3: ./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```